# How to Enable VDBG to True in Android AOSP System Classes Compiled with Userdebug?

Tags: android, android-source

I compiled the Android AOSP with userdebug and I want to enable

```
private static final boolean VDBG = false;
```

to true on system classes. How can I achieve this?

Is there a specific configuration or build flag that needs to be set during the compilation process to enable debugging options like VDBG? Or is there another approach I should take to achieve this modification in the system classes effectively?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have already tried modifying the VDBG variable in the respective system class files, but it seems like those changes don't take effect after compiling and flashing the system image onto my device.